# Django- Migrating an app from production to my local uat session - throwing appregistrynotready - Apps aren't loaded

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a prod version of a project (made by someone else) that I am trying to deploy on my laptop.

I have installed python through Anaconda 3. I have the necessary paths registered. And the code is working in the production environment without any issues. I have PostGreSQL installed and have it configured it like the prod environment.

The command I am running is

```
C:\sites\myanalysis>python manage.py makemigrations
```

The result ends with the following exception:

```
  File "C:\Users\rambo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dj
ango-2.1-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 90, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\rambo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dj
ango-2.1-py3.6.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_con
fig
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\rambo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dj
ango-2.1-py3.6.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Googling the possible issue - I have the following installed apps within the settings.py file

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'project.apps.ProjectConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

The settings.py file already has the following imported

```
import psycopg2
import os
```

Anyone can please help as to what else I can try?

Comment: just adding some additional context - version of Python on laptop = (Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bi
t (AMD64)] on win32), and version of Python on prod server = Python 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:32:42) [MSC v.1
600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Make sure you have installed the same version of Django on your laptop as in production - `django-2.1` in the traceback makes it look as if you have installed the development version of Django 2.1 locally. Please add the rest of the traceback if you've left any out.